# Reinstall rhn-client-tools with non working yum

Tags: ssl, centos, certificate, yum

For every yum command it will return SSL certificate error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security
The SSL certificate failed verification.
```

My SSL cert if valid.

I checked rhel site for https://access.redhat.com/solutions/93313 but the problem is i cannot reinstall rhn-client-tools since yum is actually not working and for some other reasons i cannot boot it from DVD/image.

Any tips on this?

Comment: Will this help: https://superuser.com/questions/1057905/adding-no-check-certificate-to-yum-repositories to reinstall the client tools?

Comment: could be a fix but i dont want to ignore cert here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to reinstall, have you also checked your firewall settings and the time and date setting on your server ?

If the firewall is not the issue, I would suggest a simpler approach, just by going to RH's site and downloading the appropriate `rhn-client-tools` RPM package, copying it to your server and installing it.

"*What about the possible dependencies?*" I foresee you asking...

- 1. Use a different server (or VM) with the same OS version that has access to the internet.
- 2. use yum with the download only plugin to only download all the needed dependencies (you must have the `yum-plugin-downloadonly` package installed beforehand) in a local directory like so:
     `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>`
- 3. Copy the packages downloaded at step #2 to your affected machine and install them using the rpm utility as so: `rpm -ivh /path/to/yum/download/dir/*`